# Passing value from select option to form action

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a problem with getting this to work, I want the user to be able to select a downloadable file and select download.

You can see the example on this link:
http://www.kawasakirobot.dk/kawasakirobot/robotter/r_-_serie_tabeludarbejdelse.aspx

But as you can see, it just adds the value of one or two an unlimited times!

like this:

...//dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58141887/oneoneoneoneoneoneoneoneone...and on and on!

Hope someone will be able to help me out!

```
<form method="post" name="downloadForm" action="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58141887/">
                <select name="selectdownload" id="selectdownload">
                <option value="one">one</option>
                <option value="two">two</option>
                </select> <input type="submit" value="Download File" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function(){
   $(this).attr('action',$(this).attr('action')+$('#selectdownload').val());
   $(this).submit();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$(this).submit();` in your submit handler, it'll make recursion.

You should do like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
   $(this).attr('action',$(this).attr('action')+$('#selectdownload').val());
   return true;
});
```